# Combining Algolia Search, Google Cloud Data & WordPress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, algolia

I have a large Google Spreadsheet (currently at 60,000 rows) which I believe is going to grow to 100,000 rows.

I would like for the data contained within this Spreadsheet to be searchable and it seems that Algolia is nicely suited to this task.

So, my question is, is my logic correct for speed and efficiency?

1. Store the data in a Google Spreadsheet Format on Google Cloud
2. Install the Alogolia WordPress Plugin;

^ Can anyone see any issues with the above?

Thanks!

Comment: This is pretty broad as there’s about 100 ways to do this, but that it a way yes – I presume you have a Step 1b where the Google Spreadsheet magically appears in your WordPress site?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Regarding the Spreadsheet I was hoping that it could be placed in a cloud SQL which Id upload and update using data from the spreadsheet?

Comment: You mean you’d do that manually?